# Access facebook wall post?

Tags: android, facebook

I want to get the all the wall post information that has been posted by the user.Is it possible to get that? I can post message on my wall through Graph API but i dont know How to get wall post..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's the news feed: https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=, and the profile feed, or wall, https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=

see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

but if you mean you want to get everything a user posted on *other people's* walls, I don't know how to do that.